# How can I combine the attendance numbers for both weekend days in a report

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 18.c.  In an Apex 19.1 application, I have the following Select statement for a chart.

```
Select
      le.prim_key
    , le.weekday
    , to_char(le.event_date, 'MON-DD-YYYY') as "Event_Date"
    , NVL(le.count_in_person, 0) as "In Person"
    , 'In_Person' series
From 
      LITURGY_EVENT le
Where
    le.prim_key is not null And
    le.weekday in ('Sat', 'Sun')
Order by
    le.event_date;
```

It works fine as-is and shows both weekend days separately.  Now I'd like to combine the **count_in_person** for both weekend events (i.e., 12/4/2021 and 12/5/2021) and offer them as one count for the mixed dates (i.e., W.E. 12/5/2021).
I can't figure out how to approach this.  I tried using a CASE statement involving the Weekday column, but I got stuck there.  It would be acceptable to use PL/SQL as a solution.  Thanks for looking at this.

The data looks like:
[image]

I'd like the output to look something like:
[image]

By the way, the **prim_key** doesn't have to be in the **Select** clause, as long as it's part of the **Where** clause.

Here's some code to create and populate the table.

```
CREATE TABLE "LITURGY_EVENT" 
   (    "PRIM_KEY" NUMBER, 
    "LITURGY_DATE" DATE, 
    "WEEKDAY" VARCHAR2(1024 BYTE), 
    "COUNT_IN_PERSON" NUMBER 
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
;
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into LITURGY_EVENT (PRIM_KEY,LITURGY_DATE,WEEKDAY,COUNT_IN_PERSON) values (1342,to_date('2021-11-27 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Sat',30);
Insert into LITURGY_EVENT (PRIM_KEY,LITURGY_DATE,WEEKDAY,COUNT_IN_PERSON) values (1241,to_date('2021-11-28 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Sun',100);
Insert into LITURGY_EVENT (PRIM_KEY,LITURGY_DATE,WEEKDAY,COUNT_IN_PERSON) values (1341,to_date('2021-12-04 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Sat',45);
Insert into LITURGY_EVENT (PRIM_KEY,LITURGY_DATE,WEEKDAY,COUNT_IN_PERSON) values (1343,to_date('2021-12-05 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'Sun',100);
```

Comment: you need a count(NVL(le.count_in_person, 0)) and GROUP BY , in which case you need to get rid of le.weekday from the select

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output in text/tabular format. Please include enough rows that cover multiple weeks to see what you expect to get for a long time frame. The easiest solution is to remove `weekend` and apply aggregation on date and count, but it may be not what you want for chart

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I edited my original post and provided a copy of week's data and desired output.

Comment: _" I edited my original post and provided a copy of week's data"_   Helpful, but better if you provided text (not screen shots) of the table DDL and representative INSERT statements.  That would allow people to copy run it on their own systems for testing.

Comment: See above.  I added the DDL and Insert statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LEAD](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LEAD.html) function to combine DB rows as a sub-query, then total the 2 days count_in_person on the outer.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f1e0c9f47c80d00e807c655bb4e6726))

```
select 'Weekend' " "
     , to_char(coalesce(ndate,liturgy_date), 'Mon-dd-yyyy' "Event Date"
     , count_in_person + coalesce(ncount,0)  "In Person"
     , 'In Person' "Series"
  from (
         select liturgy_date  
              , count_in_person 
              , weekday
              , lead (liturgy_date) over( order by liturgy_date ) ndate
              , lead (count_in_person) over( order by liturgy_date ) ncount   
           from liturgy_event 
          where weekday in ('Sat','Sun')
       )
    where weekday = 'Sat';
```

NOTE: The weekday column is redundant and potentially a source of errors. It would be possible to enter `2021-12- 05` with weekday `Sun`. Better to extract it from the date (also in demo). If really wanted in table then define it as a generated virtual column.

```
create table liturgy_event 
   (  prim_key        number, 
      liturgy_date    date, 
      count_in_person number,
      weekday         varchar2(12) generated always as (to_char(liturgy_date, 'Dy')) virtual
   ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks Belayer.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can group using `LISTAGG`

```
select
    listagg(le.prim_key, ', ') within group(
    order by
        le.prim_key
    )                       as "prim_key",
    listagg(le.weekday, ', ') within group(
    order by
        le.prim_key
    )                       as "weekday",
    listagg(to_char(le.event_date, 'MON-DD-YYYY'), ', ') within group(
    order by
        le.prim_key
    )                       as "event_date",
    sum(le.count_in_person) as "in person",
    'In_Person'             series
from
    liturgy_event le
where
    le.prim_key is not null
    and le.weekday in ( 'Sat', 'Sun' )
order by
    le.event_date;
```

[image]

Dummy table

[image: Demo Table]

Comment: Thanks for the sample Enrique.  I see what you mean by using LISTAGG.  But it doesn't give the results I need.  I edited my original post with data and expected results.  I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but I need the results aggregated for a given weekend, where the Sat is followed by the next day's Sun.  The sample above provides a single aggregated amount.  I have 80 weeks of data.  Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: Then maybe you need to create a PLSQL Block